# "Failed to initialize database."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

**Situation**
I've set up new IIS 7.5 server under Win2k8. I've moved application from shared hosting to this server.

**Problem**
I get this error:

```
Failed to initialize database.
```

The trace:

```
[SystemException: Failed to initialize database.]
   SyneoERPWeb.MvcApplication.SetupDatabase() in C:\Users\a\Desktop\src\branches\1.1\SyneoERPWeb\Global.asax.cs:194
   SyneoERPWeb.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\a\Desktop\src\branches\1.1\SyneoERPWeb\Global.asax.cs:136

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to initialize database.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9160125
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to initialize database.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9079228
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

**What I've googled and tried:**

1. Give full access to IIS_IUSER to Windows\Temp
2. Change AppPoll runs as Network Service, Local Service, Local System
3. Every ISS setting that may cause (in my opinion) this problem.

---

I've tried the remote SQL Server (IP 212.122l...) - it worked previously with our app

I've tried it also with my newly installed SQL Server on virtual machine in this same sub-network (IP 192.168...).

Both machines are responding to ping, but neither work with the app. I can connect with MSSQL Management Studio to both also.

So my guess is that the problem is local on app server. I think it occurs before the connection request. It's more like lack of some driver in IIS. Is this possible?

I'm using: NHibernate, EntytyFramewok.

Comment: Can you show us the code that the first error references?  What are you trying to do when you get the exception?  Is the `SQL Server` service running?

Comment: How did you set up this database?  Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions with "Win2k ASP.NET MVC MSSQL " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Does the sql user you are using connect to the database correctly in management studio? If that works; run profiler and see if the connection from the site is happening. If its not check the connectivity. If thats not happening check the permissions of the user in the database for the tasks being run - profiler the calls and run them in the DB as the same user.

Comment: Is your connection string correct? IE can you connect to SQL with the username and Password specified. If its using Integrated Security, does your machine account have access to SQL

Comment: Do you use same credentials and connection string to both local machine and server? Check the connection strings. Maybe you don't have rights to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your SQL Error log and the Windows Application log. Should point you in a direction.

I believe it's more on the DB side rather than your application.

In the SQL error log you will find all the databases that started up as well as the ones that did not. There should be additional info in there as to why that DB cannot start up.